# Selenium in Python shows Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have written like this

```
repos=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="execute repo-list--repo-name"]')
choice=input()
ch=repos[choice-1].text
print ch #prints choice1
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"%s"]' % ch).click()
```

for the HTML code

```
<a class="execute repo-list--repo-name" href="/vivek-puri/choice1">choice1</a>
```

But it is showing the error

```
The given selector //a[contains(text(),"choice1"] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.
```

Why it is showing such error although the element with text choice1 exits.

Comment: If you do not have other elements of with the class, use find_element_by_class_name instead

Comment: @LarsNielsen I have multiple elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of parentheses. You forgot second bracket:
use

```
//a[contains(text(),"choice1")]
```

instead of

```
//a[contains(text(),"choice1"]
```

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"%s")]' % ch).click() is also not working

Answer (score 1):

You are missing brackets after `choice1` in the selector. It should be

```
//a[contains(text(),"choice1")]
```

You can also use `by_link_text` or `by_partial_link_text`

```
find_element_by_link_text('choice1')

find_element_by_partial_link_text('choice1')
```